# How to insert multiple default rows into a table in PostgresQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, sql-insert

I have a table with columns taking default values:

```
create table indexing_table
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NOW(),
);
```

How do I insert multiple default rows into this table? Do I have to repeat the command:

```
insert into indexing_table default values;
```

as many times as I want it to be inserted?

Comment: see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89538/is-there-a-way-to-insert-multiple-rows-into-a-table-with-default-values-for-all

Comment: thanks, so something like `insert into indexing_table default VALUES from generate_series(1, 10);`?

Answer (score 3):

When you have a default value, you can tell the database to use this default value:

```
INSERT INTO indexing_table(id, created_at) 
VALUES(default, default), 
  (default, default), 
  (default, default);
```

If you need hundreds of default records and one of your defaults is "now()", use generate_series():

```
INSERT INTO indexing_table(created_at)
SELECT NOW() FROM generate_series(1,100);
```

Comment: If I wish to insert 100 rows into this table, do I have to copy and paste `(default, default),` 100 times?

Comment: @Alex: That's an option, but you could also use generate_series(), check the edited answer.

Comment: can you use `generate_series()` with `insert into table DEFAULT VALUES`?

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem. Have header table which contains only id generated by sequence. I need insert rows into snapshot table and of course i must first fill header. So i have temporary table with many rows and want insert fast to both table.

Loop is easy to write, but its not a way to optimize query (In actualization process it run several thousand times on diferent databases/schemes)

Could run insert with specific values

```
INSERT INTO csh33 (id)
    SELECT (SELECT last_value FROM csh33_id_seq) + row_number() OVER ()
        FROM temp_tss11;

-- Primary key "id" is Serial so dont name it
INSERT INTO css33 (header_id, time_from, time_to, code, name)
    SELECT (SELECT last_value FROM csh33_id_seq) + row_number() OVER (), now(), null, code, name, FROM temp_tss11;

SELECT setval('csh33_id_seq', (SELECT max(id) FROM csh33) + 1);
```

Or i could don't name fields with default values

```
INSERT INTO csh33 SELECT FROM temp_tss11;

-- But must consider raised sequence in filling snapshot table (Don't care about ordering, so only subtract)
INSERT INTO css33 (header_id, time_from, time_to, code, name)
    SELECT (SELECT last_value FROM csh33_id_seq) - row_number() OVER (), now(), null, code, name, FROM temp_tss11;
```

**But for you question**

```
INSERT INTO yourTableName SELECT generate_series(1,100)
```

Note i use PG 9.4

Answer (score 1):

An option if you do not want to name any column keeping the `default values` syntax is to build it dynamically:

```
do $$
begin
execute (
    select string_agg('insert into indexing_table default values',';')
    from generate_series(1,10)
);
end; $$;
```

[`do`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html)

[`execute`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

Answer (score -1):

The simplist way is to insert now() into the "created_at" column like so:

```
insert into indexing_table (created_at)
select now()
;
```

Comment: did you mean to add `from generate_series(1,10)`?

Comment: You could, but if you just want to insert  one record that would be the command. Or you could create a for-while loop and just re-fire the above sql statement. As a side note, this table seems pretty useless... What are you using it for?

Comment: it's just an example, this table might contain other fields which can be `NULL`. It is more important to be able to initialise the table to contain certain values for `id`. I also don't want to insert one record. If I did I believe `insert into indexing_table default values;` to be a better way.

Comment: No need for the `select`.  An `insert into indexing_table values (current_timestamp)` will do just fine. But that was not the question actually.